# How can I conditionally format this Google Sheet with multiple IFTHEN

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm collaborating on a Google Sheet with approximately 500 rows. I think potentially could use IF, ISBLANK and conditional formatting but I can't conceptualize a formula for this and I've tried reading examples. This Google Sheet has unique rows, but I cannot change the text which is why would like to conditionally format.

1. J cell should be highlighted if text is "Not Met" AND column M is blank.
2. K cell should be highlighted if text is "Not Met" AND column N is blank.
3. I is the ultimately important column and should be highlighted if (J is "Not Met" AND M is blank) or if (K is "Not Met" and N is blank). If both conditions are met it does not need to be highlighted - for example, the last row in the photo does not need to be highlighted because J is "Not Met" but is fulfilled by data in M AND K includes "Met".
4. Additionally, if L cell has any data then I should not be highlighted (overrides J,K,M,N data).

I'm unable to print in color, so don't want to highlight green for "Met" or if J thru N fulfill the requirements, it should remain as is.

Here's ideally what I want it to look like:
[image: example of conditional formatting based on values]

**Is this possible?**

Data sample provided here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uQ0NsUlHPPQcn6xQ1hS9wainDjSdj_SPpS7H9Hj49vg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: To start, the third row of Column I in your posted image is highlighted; yet the conditions you describe are not met [i.e., "should be highlighted if (J is "Not Met" AND M is blank) AND if (K is "Not Met" and N is blank)]. In addition, EXPLAINING how to implement such rules would take longer than simple implementing them. Keeping in mind that this site is tended 100% by volunteer contributors and not paid employees, the best way to invite help is to share a link to your sheet (or a copy of it) with the link permissions set (when creating the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: You can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, so that you can freely edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

The answer comprises a series of custom formula:

**Column J**
`=AND(J2="Not Met",isblank(M2))`

- Highlight if Column J = "Not Met" **AND** Column M is blank

**Column K**
`=AND(K2="Not Met",isblank(N2))`

- Highlight if Column K = "Not Met" **AND** Column N is blank

**Column I**

`=or(not(isblank(L2)),AND(AND(J2="Not Met",isblank(M2)),AND(K2="Not Met",isblank(N2))))`

- This is in two parts driven by `OR`

  - Part#1: Highlight if Column L is **not** blank
  - `not(isblank(L2))`
  - Part#2: Combination of the Column J and K rules with `AND` applied
  - `AND(AND(J2="Not Met",isblank(M2)),AND(K2="Not Met",isblank(N2)))`